# How to change only the link font to italics?

Tags: links

I am looking to change the font of only the links in the LaTeX as italics.

```
\hypersetup{%
linkcolor=black,
font=italics,
unicode%
}
```

Comment: Can you provide `MWE` of you coding?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to modify the definition of `colorlink` to change the font to italics, similar to the existing `frenchlinks` option (which changes the font to small caps). Note that the definition should be provided after `\begin{document}`, otherwise `hyperref` can overwrite the modifications with the default values.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\Hy@colorlink#1{\begingroup\fontshape{it}\selectfont}%
\makeatother
See \autoref{sec:first}.
\section{First section}
\label{sec:first}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe `\fontshape{\itdefault}` in case the italic shape of the current font isn't called `it`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik that is probably better indeed. Note that the definition of `frenchlinks` (on which my answer is based) uses `sc` and not `scdefault` - but that doesn't mean that it's right of course :)

Comment: Indeed. Try this, for example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[frenchlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{test}\label{sec:test}
See~\ref{sec:test}
\end{document}`. I get a warning: `Font shape `T1/mdugm/m/sc' undefined(Font) using `T1/mdugm/m/n' instead`. Should it be reported to the maintainer?

Answer (score -1):

if used just once or twice,

```
\textit{\url{www.url.com}}
```

or

```
\textit{\href{https://url.com}{URL}}
```

Comment: That doesn't work if the URL contains special characters, like `&` and `#`...